# What's the most appropriate type of index to use for this function-based query?

Tags: postgresql, index, functions

I'm using Postgres 9.5.  I'm going to be running a lot of this kind of query

```
SELECT * 
FROM mydb_article 
where regexp_replace(url, '\?.*$', '') = :url_wo_query_string
```

so I figured I would need to create a functional index on my table for that operation.  So I tried

```
mydb=> CREATE INDEX my_article_idx ON mydb_article regexp_replace(url, '\?.*$', '');
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "regexp_replace"
LINE 1: CREATE INDEX my_article_idx ON mydb_article regexp_repl...
```

My question is, what's the most appropriate type of index I should be using and if its the above, what else do I need to do to get things to work right?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oh, that a postgres! I've missed the tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of expressions for an index must be put between parentheses `on table_name (a,b,c)`. If the index expression is not just a column name, the expression itself must be enclosed with parentheses as well:

```
CREATE INDEX my_article_idx 
   ON mydb_article ( (regexp_replace(url, '\?.*$', '')) );
```